# Issue with adding colour to geom_mark_ellipse using scale_fill_manual in PCA plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I recently posted on how to use vectors in scale_fill_manual and got some great advice to use setNames. This has worked fine so far however now I'm having some glitches with a PCA plot that I cannot figure out.

First I have created vectors for sample names and colours as follows:

```
DGEGroup1Col <- "steelblue3"
DGEGroup2Col <- "grey56"
DGEGroup1 <- "E1E2"
DGEGroup2 <- "pCDNA"
```

Then I want to call this in a PCA plot as follows:

```
PCAP1 <- ggplot(ScoresPC1PC2)+
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, fill = Groups), size = 4.5, color = "black", shape = 21)+
  scale_fill_manual(values =setNames(c(DGEGroup1Col, DGEGroup2Col), nm = c(DGEGroup1, DGEGroup2)))+
  ggforce::geom_mark_ellipse(mapping=aes(x=PC1,y=PC2, fill= Groups, color= Groups),alpha=0.2,
                             position = position_jitter(width=0.3,height=0.3))+
  scale_colour_manual(values =setNames(c(DGEGroup1Col, DGEGroup2Col), nm = c(DGEGroup1, DGEGroup2)))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", color = "black", size = 0.8)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, linetype="dashed", color= "black", size = 0.8)+
  xlab(paste("PC1 ", "(",ExpPC1P2[1],"%)", sep=""))+
  ylab(paste("PC2 ", "(",ExpPC1P2[2],"%)", sep=""))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 18, family = "sans"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 18, family = "sans"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour ="black", size = 16, family = "sans"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour ="black", size = 16, family = "sans"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 18, family = "sans"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5),
        legend.text.align = 0,
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"))
```

This creates the following graph:
[image]

Sometimes when I run the same code I get this graph:
[image]

Ideally, I want both elipses to be filled with the respective colours and I thought that the code is correct for that. I can't understand why it doesn't and why sometimes it works for the grey sample.

Here is the dput() output of ScoresPC1PC2

```
structure(list(PC1 = c(-35.2409313607162, -23.0341545349512, 
-19.840742842832, -36.5827751478223, -28.6911983398547, -40.2380866994142, 
39.2026834777075, 37.4165448661976, 47.2975300548786, 59.7111305268072
), PC2 = c(46.8503978923974, -13.5039005407852, -5.8433732590231, 
25.7422241399349, -21.2022920781914, -42.5376795322046, 36.9581226051217, 
-25.3346801555976, 47.3421448172082, -48.4709638888607), Samps = c("E1E2 1", 
"E1E2 2", "E1E2 3", "E1E2 4", "E1E2 5", "E1E2 6", "pCDNA 1", 
"pCDNA 2", "pCDNA 3", "pCDNA 4"), Groups = c("E1E2", "E1E2", 
"E1E2", "E1E2", "E1E2", "E1E2", "pCDNA", "pCDNA", "pCDNA", "pCDNA"
)), row.names = c("E1E2 1", "E1E2 2", "E1E2 3", "E1E2 4", "E1E2 5", 
"E1E2 6", "pCDNA 1", "pCDNA 2", "pCDNA 3", "pCDNA 4"), class = "data.frame")
```

**Thanks in advance for any help!**

Comment: I can't replicate the problem.  When I run your code (removing the `xlab()` and `ylab()` lines because we don't have `ExpPC*`) I get two ellipses where the edges and fill colours are the same - blue for E1E2 and gray for pCDNA.

Comment: Hmm that's really weird, I wonder why its being glitchy on mine!